# Setting the property variable in Hive

Tags: properties, hive

I am running Hive as an action in oozie. Is there a way I can use the property variables in Hive? If yes, how do i set them? For example: When I am creating an external table, I woul dlike to set the location as a propery.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(
id bigint, 
name string  
)
row format DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY "^"
location "/user/test/data";
```

So is it possible to set location as

```
location ${input}
```

Where in I set **$(input)** in my properties file.

Comment: The variable substitution link does not seem to be active anymore. Try this http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/hive/language_manual/var_substitution.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the convention from the above question, you can access the property by using `${hiveconf:input}` in your hive commands.

In order to define a property named *input*, you would have to modify hive-site.xml and add a snippet like

```
<property>
  <name>input</name>
  <value>input_value</value>
</property>
```

However, if *input* is an environment variable (say, from bash), you can access it using `${env:input}`. For example, `${env:HOME}` or `${env:PATH}`

Answer (score 1):

You can set one with `set input=/user/test/data` and retrieve it with `${hiveconf:input}`.
A more detailed description of this can be found here [using variables](http://hive.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/language_manual/var_substitution.html)